# Acceleration due to incident radiation on plate

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, radiation, intensity

I have tried the following question and getting a wrong answer.

> Monochromatic light of intensity I falls over a blackened plate of area A, at an angle $\theta$ as shown in the figure. If 70% of light is absorbed and mass of plate is $m$. Find the acceleration of plate given wave length light is 2. Take $\theta=60^\circ$ and no other force except radiation acting on the plate.

[image]

Working : 30% is reflected. $a_r=30\%$ and $a_t=70\%$.

$$F=a_r\frac{2IA cos \theta}{c}+a_t\frac{IA}{c}$$

On solving I get $F=m*\text{acceleration}$ and $\text{acceleration}=\frac{IA}{mc}$.

The answer given is 0.44 times my answer. Where have I gone wrong?
Any hint or help is appreciated.

Comment: For some reason Mathjax is not working, if anyone could edit it I would be grateful.

Comment: Thanks @Miyase !